# Transform blockquote and lists correctly XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Dear StackOverflow Community

I am a beginner in XSLT topic and need your help in completing my XSLT file.

I have the following source xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<k4Export xmlns="http://www.vjoon.com/K4Export/2.6"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" format="intermediate" version="2.6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vjoon.com/K4Export/2.6 K4Export_2_6.xsd">
    <publication>
        <id>1623922730691</id>
        <name>Digital First</name>
        <displayName>Digital First Topix</displayName>
        <origin>Standalone XMLExporter Sample Configuration</origin>
        <issue>
            <article>
                <attachment>
                    <id>24972</id>
                    <objectType>2</objectType>
                    <textObject>
                        <id>24972</id>
                        <k4ObjectID>24971</k4ObjectID>
                        <name>Bedeutung Descartes gilt als der Begründer des mod</name>
                        <objectVersion>908</objectVersion>
                        <objectVersionDateTime>2021-08-16T08:25:42Z</objectVersionDateTime>
                        <objectType>2</objectType>
                        <wfChannel>
                            <id>23370</id>
                            <originalID>1565</originalID>
                            <name>Artikel [Print]</name>
                            <outputChannel>
                                <id>23214</id>
                                <originalID>1061</originalID>
                                <name>Print</name>
                            </outputChannel>
                            <workflow>
                                <id>23369</id>
                                <originalID>1065</originalID>
                                <wfDefinitionType>1</wfDefinitionType>
                                <name>Artikel</name>
                            </workflow>
                        </wfChannel>
                        <section>
                            <id>49</id>
                            <name>Digital First</name>
                            <displayName>Digital First</displayName>
                        </section>
                        <status>
                            <id>23398</id>
                            <name>Content erstellt</name>
                        </status>
                        <layoutID>24802</layoutID>
                        <workflowActive>true</workflowActive>
                        <text>
                            <inlineTag name="Textabschnitt">
                                <inlineTag name="h1">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="blockquote">„ Das wird eine ‚Tosca‘, die man so noch nicht gesehen hat. “<break type="paragraph" /></inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="blockquote-cite">Roland Geyer, Intendant Theater an der Wien</inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="ul">eine Erkenntnistheorie, die nur das als richtig akzeptiert, was durch die eigene schrittweise Analyse und logische Reflexion als plausibel verifiziert wird,<break type="paragraph" />
                            </inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="ul">eine Ethik, gemäß der das Individuum sich im Sinne bewährter gesellschaftlicher Konventionen pflichtbewusst und moralisch zu verhalten hat,<break type="paragraph" />
                            </inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="ul">eine Metaphysik, die zwar (durch logischen Beweis) die Existenz eines vollkommenen Schöpfer-Gottes annimmt, aber kirchenartigen Institutionen wenig Raum lässt,<break type="paragraph" />
                            </inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="ul">eine Physik, die die Natur als durch zwar gottgegebene, aber allgemein gültige Gesetze geregelt betrachtet und dem Menschen ihre rationale Erklärung und damit letztlich ihre Beherrschung zur Aufgabe macht.<break type="paragraph" />
                            </inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="p">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="ol">zunächst lateinisch gedruckt wurden 1641 in Paris die Méditations sur la philosophie première, dans laquelle sont démontrées l’existence de Dieu et l’immortalité de l’âme (so der Titel einer französischen Übersetzung von 1647; deutsch «Meditationen über die Erste Philosophie, in der die Existenz Gottes und die Unsterblichkeit der Seele bewiesen wird»). Die zweite Auflage 1642 in Amsterdam erschien mit geändertem Untertitel, «denn ich kann nicht beweisen, dass Gott die Seele nicht vernichten könnte, sondern nur, dass sie von völlig anderer Natur als der Körper ist und nicht mit dem Körper stirbt» (Brief an Marin Mersenne vom 24. Dezember 1640). Der Untertitel lautete nun: Méditations sur la philosophie première, dans laquelle sont démontrées l’existence de Dieu et la distinction de l’âme et du corps (deutsch «Meditationen über die Erste Philosophie, in der die Existenz Gottes und der Unterschied zwischen Seele und Körper bewiesen wird»).<break type="paragraph" />
                            </inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="ol">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="blockquote">„ Das wird eine ‚Tosca‘, die man so noch nicht gesehen hat. “<break type="paragraph" /></inlineTag>
                            <inlineTag name="blockquote-cite">Roland Geyer, Intendant Theater an der Wien</inlineTag>
                        <inlineTag name="p">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</inlineTag>
                        </inlineTag>
                    </text>
                </textObject>
            </attachment>
        </article>
    </issue>
</publication>
</k4Export>
```

and my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="k4 xsl" version="1.0"
    xmlns:k4="http://www.vjoon.com/K4Export/2.6" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="k4:*"/>
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="k4:k4Export/k4:publication/k4:issue/k4:article"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="k4:article">
        <xsl:variable name="workflow" select="./k4:wfChannel/k4:workflow/k4:name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="channel" select="./k4:wfChannel/k4:outputChannel/k4:name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="category" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='WP Kategorie']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="author" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='Author']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="post_tag" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Keywords']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="status" select="./k4:status/k4:name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_synonyms" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Synonyms']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_keywords" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Keywords']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_meta_description" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Meta Description']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_title" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Title']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="wp_category" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='WP Kategorie']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="field_author" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='Author']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="wfObjectVariantId" select="./k4:id"/>
        <export>
            <xsl:attribute name="wfObjectVariantId">
                <xsl:value-of select="$wfObjectVariantId"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_workflow</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$workflow"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_channel</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$channel"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">category</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$category"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">author</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$author"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">post_tag</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$post_tag"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_status</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$status"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_synonyms</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_synonyms"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_keywords</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_keywords"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_meta_description</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_meta_description"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_title</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_title"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_wp_kategorie</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$wp_category"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_author</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$field_author"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./k4:attachment"/>
        </export>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="k4:table" name="handleTable">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="k4:attachment">
        <xsl:for-each select="k4:textObject/k4:text">
            <textobject>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </textobject>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="k4:other">
        <image>
            <imgname>
                <xsl:value-of select="./k4:preview/k4:file"/>
            </imgname>
            <caption>
                <xsl:value-of select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Caption DE']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
            </caption>
        </image>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


    
    <!-- Sucht nach InDesign Tags und erstellt basierend auf ihnen HTML-Tags mit Klasse «imported» für das CSS -->
    <xsl:template match="k4:inlineTag/k4:inlineTag">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='h1'">
                <h1 class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </h1>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='h2'">
                <h2 class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </h2>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='h3'">
                <h3 class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </h3>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='h4'">
                <h4 class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </h4>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='h5'">
                <h5 class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </h5>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='h6'">
                <h6 class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </h6>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='p'">
                <p class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='body'">
                <p class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='[Einf. Abs.]'">
                <p class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='[Basic Paragraph]'">
                <p class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='strong'">
                <b class="imported">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </b>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='bold'">
                <b class="imported">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </b>    
            </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="./@name='i'">
                <i class="imported">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </i>    
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:when test="./@name='a'">
                <a class="imported">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="./k4:attribute/@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </a>    
            </xsl:when>   
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--<p class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </p>-->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-namespaces" select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export wfObjectVariantId="">
   <metadata name="field_workflow"/>
   <metadata name="field_channel"/>
   <metadata name="category"/>
   <metadata name="author"/>
   <metadata name="post_tag"/>
   <metadata name="field_status"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_synonyms"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_keywords"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_meta_description"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_title"/>
   <metadata name="field_wp_kategorie"/>
   <metadata name="field_author"/>
   <textobject>
      <h1 class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</h1>
      <p class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</p>
      <p class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</p>
   </textobject>
</export>
```

So as you can see from the output, I can transform the formats (h1/p) correctly.
But if I were to just add the things in the xsl:choose now:

```
<xsl:when test="./@name='ul'">
                <li class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='ol'">
                <li class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='blockquote'">
                <blockquote class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </blockquote>    
            </xsl:when>
```

Then, of course, the blockquote and the list items are taken, but not correctly.

When I run this XSLT transformation, I get the correct results for the lists and for the blockquote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="k4 xsl" version="1.0"
    xmlns:k4="http://www.vjoon.com/K4Export/2.6" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="k4:*"/>
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="k4:k4Export/k4:publication/k4:issue/k4:article"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="k4:article">
        <xsl:variable name="workflow" select="./k4:wfChannel/k4:workflow/k4:name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="channel" select="./k4:wfChannel/k4:outputChannel/k4:name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="category" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='WP Kategorie']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="author" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='Author']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="post_tag" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Keywords']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="status" select="./k4:status/k4:name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_synonyms" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Synonyms']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_keywords" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Keywords']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_meta_description" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Meta Description']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="seo_title" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Title']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="wp_category" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='WP Kategorie']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="field_author" select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='Author']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="wfObjectVariantId" select="./k4:id"/>
        <export>
            <xsl:attribute name="wfObjectVariantId">
                <xsl:value-of select="$wfObjectVariantId"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_workflow</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$workflow"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_channel</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$channel"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">category</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$category"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">author</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$author"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">post_tag</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$post_tag"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_status</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$status"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_synonyms</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_synonyms"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_keywords</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_keywords"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_meta_description</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_meta_description"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_seo_title</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$seo_title"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_wp_kategorie</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$wp_category"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="metadata">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">field_author</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="$field_author"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./k4:attachment"/>
        </export>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="k4:table" name="handleTable">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="k4:attachment">
        <xsl:for-each select="k4:textObject/k4:text">
            <textobject>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </textobject>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="k4:other">
        <image>
            <imgname>
                <xsl:value-of select="./k4:preview/k4:file"/>
            </imgname>
            <caption>
                <xsl:value-of select="./k4:metaData[k4:name='SEO Caption DE']/k4:metaDataValue/k4:string"/>
            </caption>
        </image>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>



    
    <!-- Hier wird Blockquote/UL übernommen -->
    <xsl:template match="/k4:k4Export/k4:publication/k4:issue/k4:article/k4:attachment/k4:textObject/k4:text/k4:inlineTag">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="k4:inlineTag" group-starting-with="blockquote">
            <blockquote>
                <xsl:attribute name="cite"><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::k4:inlineTag[@name='blockquote-cite']]"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::k4:inlineTag[@name='blockquote']]"/>
            </blockquote>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@name = 'ol'">   
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <ol>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/> 
                    </ol>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@name = 'ul'">   
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/> 
                    </ul>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="k4:inlineTag/k4:inlineTag">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='ol'">
                <li class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>    
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@name='ul'">
                <li class="imported">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </li>    
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>




    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-namespaces" select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export wfObjectVariantId="">
   <metadata name="field_workflow"/>
   <metadata name="field_channel"/>
   <metadata name="category"/>
   <metadata name="author"/>
   <metadata name="post_tag"/>
   <metadata name="field_status"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_synonyms"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_keywords"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_meta_description"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_title"/>
   <metadata name="field_wp_kategorie"/>
   <metadata name="field_author"/>
   <textobject>
      <blockquote cite="Roland Geyer, Intendant Theater an der Wien">„ Das wird eine ‚Tosca‘, die man so noch nicht gesehen hat. “</blockquote>
      <ol>
         <li class="imported">zunächst lateinisch gedruckt...</li>
         <li class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich...</li>
      </ol>
      <ul>
         <li class="imported">eine Erkenntnistheorie, die..</li>
         <li class="imported">eine Ethik, gemäß...</li>
         <li class="imported">eine Metaphysik, die...</li>
         <li class="imported">eine Physik, die ...</li>
      </ul>
   </textobject>
</export>
```

So here the blockquote and the blockquote cite is taken correctly.
I need your help now, as I lack the knowledge unfortunately. How can I now combine these two stylesheets logically with each other and functionally so that I get the following result?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export wfObjectVariantId="">
   <metadata name="field_workflow"/>
   <metadata name="field_channel"/>
   <metadata name="category"/>
   <metadata name="author"/>
   <metadata name="post_tag"/>
   <metadata name="field_status"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_synonyms"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_keywords"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_meta_description"/>
   <metadata name="field_seo_title"/>
   <metadata name="field_wp_kategorie"/>
   <metadata name="field_author"/>
   <textobject>
      <h1 class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich ins Französische übersetzt wurde die Schrift Principia philosophiae («Grundlagen der Philosophie», 1644).</h1>
      <blockquote cite="Roland Geyer, Intendant Theater an der Wien">„ Das wird eine ‚Tosca‘, die man so noch nicht gesehen hat. “</blockquote>
      <ul>
         <li class="imported">eine Erkenntnistheorie, die...</li>
         <li class="imported">eine Ethik, gemäß...</li>
         <li class="imported">eine Metaphysik, die...</li>
         <li class="imported">eine Physik, die...</li>
      </ul>
      <blockquote cite="Roland Geyer, Intendant Theater an der Wien">„ Das wird eine ‚Tosca‘, die man so noch nicht gesehen hat. “</blockquote>
      <p class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich...</p>
      <ol>
         <li class="imported">zunächst lateinisch gedruckt...</li>
         <li class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich...</li>
      </ol>
      <p class="imported">Ebenfalls erst nachträglich...</p>
   </textobject>
</export>
```

Comment: One question to ask yourself is ... "do I have a good reason to combine them?" There are many applications where one applies a progressive set of XSLs to get the desired output. Passing output of one ro input of another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in the template doing the grouping you rather want some generic `group-adjacent="@name"` and then distinguish e.g. instead of

```
<xsl:template match="/k4:k4Export/k4:publication/k4:issue/k4:article/k4:attachment/k4:textObject/k4:text/k4:inlineTag">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="k4:inlineTag" group-starting-with="blockquote">
        <blockquote>
            <xsl:attribute name="cite"><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::k4:inlineTag[@name='blockquote-cite']]"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::k4:inlineTag[@name='blockquote']]"/>
        </blockquote>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@name = 'ol'">   
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <ol>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/> 
                </ol>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@name = 'ul'">   
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/> 
                </ul>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

you want

```
<xsl:template match="/k4:k4Export/k4:publication/k4:issue/k4:article/k4:attachment/k4:textObject/k4:text/k4:inlineTag">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="k4:inlineTag" group-adjacent="replace(@name, '-cite$', '')">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'blockquote'">
             <blockquote cite="{current-group()[2]}">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             </blockquote>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = ('ul', 'ol')">
             <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
             </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

If there can be adjacent `blockquote`s in the input, you would need to use `<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="k4:inlineTag[@name = 'blockquote']">..</xsl:for-each-group>` inside of the `<xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 'blockquote'">` to split them up in separate `blockquote` results.

Comment: I don't know how you could give such a short, perfect and on-target answer from my original question. You really are an angel, so it works perfectly!